Unable to write text into Notes.app using AppleScript
I am trying to write into Notes.app using AppleScript and System Events.  I have the following simple script:
on test(notesAccount, notesFolder, notesName)
    
    tell application "Notes"
        activate
        delay 1.0
        tell account notesAccount
            delay 1.0
            make new note at folder notesFolder with properties {name:notesName}
            delay 1.0
            tell application "System Events"
                delay 1.0
                tell process "Notes"
                    delay 1.0
                    keystroke "Hello World"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    
end test

test("iCloud", "Notes", "Test")

When I run this script, the note gets created with the appropriate name, but no text is inserted. I do get a "beep" sound, presumably, an indication of an error.  I am currently running Sequoia 15.1. Accessibility is enabled for Script Editor.
I realize that there are alternative methods of writing text into a note. However, for other reasons, I need to use System Events.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
UPDATE:
I was unable to get the "key code" method (see answer below) to work. However, I was able to get the "Open Note in New Window" to work!
Here is a solution that works based upon red_menace's answer:
    on test(notesAccount, notesFolder, notesName)
    
    tell application "Notes"
        activate
        delay 1.0
        tell account notesAccount
            delay 1.0
            show (make new note at folder notesFolder with properties {name:notesName})
            delay 1.0
            tell application "System Events" to tell process "Notes"
                click menu item "Open Note in New Window" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
                delay 1.0
                keystroke "Hello World!"
                delay 1.0
                tell application "Notes" to if it is running then close its front window
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    
end test

test("iCloud", "Notes", "Test")

I would have preferred the "key code" method because it's visually cleaner, but this works well and I am happy! Thanks red_menace!

For GUI scripting, you would need to select the actual note, not its entry in the folder list.  Notes doesn't have a handy command for that, but you can show the note, then click in the note body, keystroke using arrow navigation, or select the "Open Note in New Window" menu item.
The following snippet (tested in macos 14 Sonoma) uses key codes to move the insertion point to the end of the new note:
      show (make new note at folder notesFolder with properties {name:notesName}) -- select note
      delay 0.25 -- adjust as needed
      tell application "System Events"
         key code {124, 125} using {command down} -- right, down arrow to move to end of note
         keystroke "Hello World"
      end tell


Unfortunately, the select the note using key codes approach did not work for me. I still just get the "Beeps".  However, the "Open Note in New Window" did work!  I prefer the key code approach. do you have any additional suggestion?

@user1092808 - I just experimented with the navigation keys (various modifiers with arrow keys vs home/end/pg up/pg dn and then used them in the script.  You may also need to adjust the delay for showing the note.
